# Connecting a texture node to a material node via the Blender Python API for Blender 2.82

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I am a newbie in Blender Python scripting. I am trying to write a simple script to link a texture node to a material node in Blender 2.82. I tried something close to the procedure described in [How can I connect a texture node to a material with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95530/how-can-i-connect-a-texture-node-to-a-material-with-python)

```
import os, bpy

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'

# new material
mat = bpy.data.materials.new('mat')
mat.use_nodes = True
matnodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

#new texture
tex = matnodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
img = bpy.data.images.load(<file-path-on-disk>)
tex.image = img

# assign texture to material's displacement
disp = matnodes['Material Output'].inputs[2]
mat.node_tree.links.new(disp, tex.outputs[0])
```

The script runs with no error reported on the console. Yet the texture node does not show on the 'Shading' panel. Can anybody give me a clue as to what may be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The script works, however you don't assign the newly created material to any object. Therefore you're seeing the old material, that was previously assigned to the active object, in the *Material Properties* or the *Shader Editor*.

If you want to assign the material to the currently active material slot of the active object, you can use

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.active_material = mat
```

where `mat` is the material you've created in your script. Alternatively you can also assign the material to a specific material slot, e.g. the first one in the following example:

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.material_slots[0].material = mat
```

When you're performing multiple operations with the active object, you can store it in a variable. It's not necessary to access it through `bpy.context` all the time.

---

One problem with your script is that it creates a node setup which doesn't properly use displacement. Usually you'd want to add a *Displacement* node and control the height through the texture. You may also want to add a *Texture Coordinate* node to use the active UV map for the displacement texture.

```
import bpy


# Create a material
material = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Example_Material")
material.use_nodes = True
nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
links = material.node_tree.links

# Reuse the material output node that is created by default
material_output = nodes.get("Material Output")

# Create Image Texture node and load the displacement texture.
# You need to add the actual path to the texture.
displacement_tex = nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexImage")
displacement_tex.image = bpy.data.images.load("/path/to/your/texture")
displacement_tex.image.colorspace_settings.name = "Non-Color"

# Create the Displacement node
displacement = nodes.new("ShaderNodeDisplacement")

# Create the Texture Coordinate node
tex_coordinate = nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexCoord")

# Connect the Texture Coordinate node to the displacement texture.
# This uses the active UV map of the object.
links.new(displacement_tex.inputs["Vector"], tex_coordinate.outputs["UV"])

# Connect the displacement texture to the Displacement node
links.new(displacement.inputs["Height"], displacement_tex.outputs["Color"])

# Connect the Displacement node to the Material Output node
links.new(material_output.inputs["Displacement"], displacement.outputs["Displacement"])

# Get the active object
active_obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active

# Check if the active object has a material slot, create one if it doesn't. 
# Assign the material to the first slot for the active object.
if active_obj.material_slots:
    active_obj.material_slots[0].material = material
else:
    active_obj.material_slots.append(material)
```

For *Adaptive Displacement* you will also have to set the *Feature Set* to experimental

```
bpy.context.scene.cycles.feature_set = 'EXPERIMENTAL'
```

and enable the *Adaptive* option in the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. You may have to adjust the *Subdivision* options in the *Render Properties* as well, in order to get the desired amount detail for the displacement.

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: @user89301 If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Thanks a million!