# How to apply a texture via Python?

Tags: python, scripting, materials, node-editor

I'm not at all sure what the title of this question should be.  In the following image, you can see how I've used the Shading editor to create a texture.

[image]

What I want to do is to do this via python.  I would like a single script to both create my mesh, and fill in all it's faces (these things I can do), *and* define and apply a procedural texture. I've been searching for tutorials for how to do this, and found several that show me how to create custom nodes (and even node groups..), but.. that's not what I'm after. I've found this: [Part of the solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95530/how-can-i-connect-a-texture-node-to-a-material-with-python?answertab=oldest#tab-top), but it seems to me like there must be a tutorial that covers this more comprehensively.. I just don't know what key-words to use yet to find it. Any help appreciated, including with figuring out what the title of this question should actually be.

Comment: Node types are hard to guess sometimes, in your case it is `VALTORGB` (color ramp) and `TEX_WAVE` (wave texture). Also no need to create any texture in this case, just create the material, done. Recommend try to understand how blender works then re-create all the necessary steps using python.

Comment: @brockmann  -time will tell, but it certainly looks helpful!  thanks!

Comment: That's all what to need to know to create a shader, once you understand the principles of that post (50lines of code) you can create whatever your want...

Comment: @brockmann that, plus this:  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Materials_and_Textures I needed to see.  I've got plenty more research ahead of me.. cheers! :-D